# Get private field types of current class,composed class,super class using reflection api

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, apache-commons

Here is my scenario:

```
Class A{
private Long aId;
}

Class C{
private BigDecimal decValue;
}

Class B extends A{
private Integer intValue;
private C c;
}
```

I have an instance of Class B(B b = new B()). with this instance of b i am trying to retrieve type of field aId in classA and type of field decValue in Class C.

I tried:
 Based on [this java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html)

```
  b.getDeclaredField("intValue").getType();//this works
    b.getDeclaredField("aId").getType();//Doesnt work, private field in super class
    b.getDeclaredField("decValue").getType();//Doesnt work, private field in composed
```

class
  I also tried getField, this doesnt give access to private fields.

what i am expecting:

```
 b.getDeclaredField("aId").getType();//should return Long.Class.
  b.getDeclaredField("decValue").getType();//Should return BigDecimal.class
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no such concept of _composed class_ in the language or in the reflection API. You'll need to get the `C` field and reflect on its type.

Comment: First line from the table from the doc you've linked: "getDeclaredField() - inherited members? no", so why do you expect to get anything for `aId`?

Comment: @user3707125 i just showed what i tried and is not working. i am not expecting getDeclaredField to work on inherited fields. My be my expectation section should be changed.I will edit it. sorry.

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting, but the best you can hope for is `b.getDeclaredField("c").getType().getDeclaredField("decValue").getType()` to return `BigDecimal.class`.